# Incompatible types since an instance of List is never an instance of AggregateResult

Tags: apex, visualforce, aggregate, aggregateresult

I am trying to execute following apex class , But facing the following error Incompatible types since an instance of List is never an instance of AggregateResult.

I am using the below code:

```
public with sharing class Eisai_Banzel_Survey_Cls{

    public list<Schema.AggregateResult> listSurvey = new list<Schema.AggregateResult>();
    private static String UserRoleId = Userinfo.getUserRoleId();
    List<UserRole> listRole = new List<UserRole>();
    List<String> listRoleIds = new List<String>();

    public list<Survey_Target_vod__c> getSurveylist(){

        listRoleIds.add(UserRoleId );

        Set<Id> allSubRoleIds = getAllSubRoleIds(new Set<ID>{UserRoleId});

        //Get all the Surveys to be displayed that would be visible to the user as per role hierarchy and sorted according to terriotry

        listSurvey = [SELECT Status_vod__c, Territory_vod__c,Count(Id), User_vod__r.Name,User_vod__r.UserRoleId, User_vod__r.IsActive 
                      FROM Survey_Target_vod__c 
                      WHERE CreatedDate = THIS_YEAR 
                      AND (OwnerId =:Userinfo.getUserId() OR User_vod__r.UserRoleId IN :allSubRoleIds ) 
                      AND User_vod__r.IsActive = TRUE
                      GROUP BY Status_vod__c,Territory_vod__c,User_vod__r.Name,User_vod__r.UserRoleId, User_vod__r.IsActive
                      ORDER BY Territory_vod__c ASC NULLS FIRST];


        if(listSurvey.size()>0){
            return listSurvey;
        }        

        else return null;

        return null;
    }

    private static Set<ID> getAllSubRoleIds(Set<ID> roleIds) {

        Set<ID> currentRoleIds = new Set<ID>();

        // get all of the roles underneath the passed roles
        for(UserRole userRole :[select Id from UserRole where ParentRoleId 
                                IN :roleIds AND ParentRoleID != null])
            currentRoleIds.add(userRole.Id);

        // go fetch some more rolls!
        if(currentRoleIds.size() > 0)
            currentRoleIds.addAll(getAllSubRoleIds(currentRoleIds));

        return currentRoleIds;

    }

}
```

Facing the error in return listSurvey; :

```
if(listSurvey.size()>0){
    return listSurvey;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

When you execute a query that includes a `GROUP BY` term it is always an array (list) of AggregateResult objects that is returned - see [Working with SOQL Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm).

So your method will have to return that type:

```
public AggregateResult[] getSurveylist() {
    ...
    return [SELECT Status_vod__c s, Territory_vod__c t,Count(Id) c, User_vod__r.Name n,User_vod__r.UserRoleId r, User_vod__r.IsActive a
                  FROM Survey_Target_vod__c 
                  WHERE CreatedDate = THIS_YEAR 
                  AND (OwnerId =:Userinfo.getUserId() OR User_vod__r.UserRoleId IN :allSubRoleIds ) 
                  AND User_vod__r.IsActive = TRUE
                  GROUP BY Status_vod__c,Territory_vod__c,User_vod__r.Name,User_vod__r.UserRoleId, User_vod__r.IsActive
                  ORDER BY Territory_vod__c ASC NULLS FIRST];
}
```

and any other code using the returned result will have to access the values using [get(fieldName)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_get).

So to get the various values in Apex (where I've added an alias in the above query for each field):

```
for (AggregateResult ar: getSurveylist()) {
    String status = (String) ar.get('s');
    String territory = (String) ar.get('t');
    Integer count = (Integer) ar.get('c');
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you are supposed to be returning

```
list<Survey_Target_vod__c>
```

but you are actually returning

```
list<Schema.AggregateResult>
```

So you'll need to make them compatible...

Comment: When using list<Survey_Target_vod__c> I get, the following error :           Illegal assignment from List<AggregateResult>to List <Survey_Target_vod__c>

Comment: When using list<Survey_Target_vod__c> I get, the following error :           Illegal assignment from List<AggregateResult>to List <Survey_Target_vod__c>.  As I am using the Aggregate method, the return type is not supported as per error. So I am making this change.   Please let me know if there is anything that I am missing here.  Thanks!